# Cellfun with Structfun as function?

Tags: matlab, function, handle, anonymous

My data are in the form of a cell array of structs. I am trying to implement a cellfun call that takes structfun as its function that, at the end of the day, will resize all of the vectors in the struct to the passed-in size. E.g. I have a 4-cell array each with a struct that contains one vector (going to be multiple vectors once I figure this out), and I want to resize each vector from index1 to index2

```
fun = function(foo, index1, index2) 
cellfun(@structfun(@(x) x(index1:index2), foo, 'UniformOutput',false), foo, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Do I have to do a loop and replace the first "foo" with "foo(i)" to be able to reach all the cells? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your cell array of structs look like? Why do you have a cell array of structs in the first place?

Comment: @excaza I have that setup because that's how my boss stores the results of the experiment. Can't change that, unfortunately. My cell array, foo, is a "1x4 struct array with fields: a b c d" is what Matlab says. Each of a,b,c,d, is a 10x1 vector. 
P.S. I persist with an array of structs instead of a struct of arrays partly because of [this](http://matlabrecipes.com/structures-of-arrays-vs-arrays-of-structures/)

Comment: You cannot inline structfun like that. You need to create a temporary function handle which calls structfun and use that in cellfun. sf = @(y) structfun(y(1:2), y, 'UniformOutput',false); cellfun(sf, ...

Comment: @Navan thank you very much.

Comment: If that helped, I will post my comment as answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inline structfun like that. You need to create a temporary function handle which calls structfun and use that in cellfun.

```
sf = @(y) structfun(@(x) x(1:2), y, 'UniformOutput',false); 
cellfun(sf, foo, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

You can do this in one line as below. But it is better to keep this in two lines for readability.

```
cellfun(@(y) structfun(@(x) x(1:2), y, 'UniformOutput',false), foo, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Your code has issues. The first argument to `structfun` need to be a function handle. You can still put everything on one line...